Firmware locked 2012 MacBook Pro Install alternate operating system?
I have a 2012 Macbook Pro, a donation. I did an Internet Recovery and installed Catalina. and it registered with an MDM, so I could not log in. I was able to contact the former owner and got it cleared from the MDM. Now, it has no accounts. And it also has a firmware password. I'm stuck.
I took it to the Apple store who told me they no longer have the tools to reset the BIOS on this unit. Looks like my only option is to desolder the BIOS and flash in a new virgin BIOS. I don't have the tools for that.
The drive is NOT protected with FileVault2, and I can mount it on another machine.
Here are my options, as I see it, but I don't know how to do any of them:

Install MacOS on a new drive, and somehow convince the password protected machine to boot the new drive. Is this just a matter of matching the UUID, or is the volume tied to the machine BIOS in a more sophisticated way?
Add a user to the existing drive, or change the password of an existing user like root to allow me to log into that drive.

Are either of these things possible? How?
I did extract the username plist files and it seems to be possible to extract the ShadowHashData and try to get the password with hashcat, but I'd prefer a simpler path.
If I can just add accounts to the existing Catalina install or drop in a newly installed disk from another Mac, that would put this idle Mac to work. Otherwise it's scrap.
